Google Maps javascript: issue with custom markers appearing on wrong positions
I'm using google maps javascript to render custom markers on my map, right now all my markers appear to be floating on the wrong positions, all of them aligned on a vertical line, one below another (check image), I don't know what is happening and tried with chatgpt to fix but no luck.
When I move around on the map the markers are moved to the same position on the screen so they are always floating on the middle of the screen...
Image: https://i.imgur.com/INxOcj9.png
My vue.js component :
<template>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100vh; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; position:relative; overflow:hidden;">
      <div v-if="!googleMapsLoaded" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; overflow:hidden;">
        <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-pulse fs_bigger c_secondary" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div :id="id" class="GOOGLEmap1"></div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'GoogleMap1',
  
    data() {
      return {
        map: null,
        googleMapsLoaded: false,
        markers: [], // Store custom markers
        mapInteracted: false, // Flag to track user interaction
      };
    },
  
    props: {
      id: { default: 'map', type: String },
      places: { type: Array, required: true }
    },
  
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$options.name + ' component successfully mounted');
      this.initMap();
    },
  
    watch: {
      places: {
        deep: true,
        handler(newPlaces) {
          if (!this.googleMapsLoaded) return;
          this.clearMarkers();
  
          // Only fitBounds if the user has not interacted with the map yet
          if (!this.mapInteracted) {
            this.fitBounds();
          }
  
          newPlaces.forEach(place => {
            this.createCustomMarker(place);
          });
        }
      }
    },
  
    methods: {
      // Check if the map is fully loaded
      checkMapLoaded() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'tilesloaded', () => {
          this.googleMapsLoaded = true;
          console.log('Google Maps loaded successfully');
  
          // Add markers once map is ready and fit the map bounds
          this.places.forEach(place => {
            this.createCustomMarker(place);
          });
          if (!this.mapInteracted) {
            this.fitBounds();
          }
        });
      },
  
      // Initialize the map with options
      initMap() {
        const myOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.places[0].coordinates.lat, this.places[0].coordinates.lng),
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          scaleControl: false,
          zoomControl: true // Keep zoom control for better UX
        };
  
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.id), myOptions);
  
        // Detect user interaction with the map (pan or zoom)
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', () => {
          this.mapInteracted = true; // Once user moves/zooms, stop calling fitBounds
        });
  
        this.checkMapLoaded(); // Check if the map is loaded before adding markers
      },
  
      // Create custom markers with your specified layout
      createCustomMarker(place) {
        if (!this.googleMapsLoaded) {
          console.log('Google Maps is not yet loaded. Cannot add markers.');
          return;
        }
  
        const position = new google.maps.LatLng(place.coordinates.lat, place.coordinates.lng);
  
        // Create the HTML content for the custom marker
        const markerContent = document.createElement('div');
        markerContent.innerHTML = `
          <div class="shadow" style="width:95px; height:95px; border-radius:50%; border:2px solid white; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; position:relative;">
            <div style="background-image:url('${place.images[0]}'); width:90px; border:2px solid white; height:90px; border-radius:50%; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; position:relative; background-size:cover; background-position:center;"></div>
            <div class="bc_secondary" style="width:30px; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; position:absolute; bottom:-5px; right:-5px; border-radius:50%;">
              <span class="fs_normal semi_bold c_light">${place.id}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        `;
  
        // Add click event listener to the custom marker
        markerContent.addEventListener('click', () => {
          alert(`Clicked on place with ID: ${place.id}`);
        });
  
        // Use OverlayView to add the custom marker to the map
        const overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
        overlay.onAdd = function() {
          const panes = this.getPanes();
          panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(markerContent);
        };
  
        overlay.draw = function() {
          const projection = this.getProjection();
          const positionPixel = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(position);
  
          if (positionPixel) {
            // Center the marker based on its width (95px)
            markerContent.style.left = `${positionPixel.x - (95 / 2)}px`; 
            markerContent.style.top = `${positionPixel.y - (95 / 2)}px`; 
          }
        };
  
        overlay.setMap(this.map);
  
        // Save the marker reference
        this.markers.push(overlay);
      },
  
      // Fit map bounds to show all markers
      fitBounds() {
        const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        this.places.forEach(place => {
          bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(place.coordinates.lat, place.coordinates.lng));
        });
        this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
      },
  
      // Clear markers from the map
      clearMarkers() {
        this.markers.forEach(marker => {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        this.markers = []; // Clear the markers array
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  .GOOGLEmap1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  </style>
  

